# find out the value of a specific variable in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a data frame with 2 columns, 1st column contains the activities such as work, home, sleep etc. and the 2nd column are the duration of each activity.

while iterating through the rows, I want to find out the duration of the last activity of 'sleep' during the current activity I am in.

Is there an easy way to do that?

my data:

```
duration = np.random.randint(20, size = 30)
activities = ['work', 'home', 'sleep', 'home','work', 'sleep','work', 'home','sleep', 'home','work', 'sleep','work', 'home','work', 'sleep','work', 'home','work', 'sleep','work', 'home','work', 'sleep','work', 'home','work', 'home', 'work', 'sleep']
activity_df = pd.DataFrame({'activities':activities, 'duration':duration})
```

Comment: What is expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need first filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and last select last value by `iloc`:

```
print (activity_df.loc[activity_df['activities'] == 'sleep', 'duration'].iloc[-1])
```

Or use [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) for create `NaN`s by condition and last forward replace values by `ffill`:

```
activity_df['new'] = activity_df['duration'].where(activity_df['activities']=='sleep').ffill()
print (activity_df)
   activities  duration   new
0        work         1   NaN
1        home         5   NaN
2       sleep        11  11.0
3        home         8  11.0
4        work        11  11.0
5       sleep         8   8.0
6        work         9   8.0
7        home        13   8.0
8       sleep        19  19.0
9        home         6  19.0
10       work        19  19.0
11      sleep        16  16.0
12       work        16  16.0
13       home         1  16.0
14       work         5  16.0
15      sleep        10  10.0
16       work         1  10.0
17       home         5  10.0
18       work         0  10.0
19      sleep         4   4.0
20       work        12   4.0
21       home         4   4.0
22       work        10   4.0
23      sleep         6   6.0
24       work        17   6.0
25       home        14   6.0
26       work         7   6.0
27       home         5   6.0
28       work        10   6.0
29      sleep         8   8.0
```

Comment: thank you I think I can complete my function with this

Comment: you are a god of stack overflow

Comment: @MarvieDemit - I think not, there is many better coders, but maybe have no enough time to answering.

Comment: I am sure there are but this is just my personal impression, that your just seconds away answering my questions, mostly dumb but important question for me as a new python coder! I just saw that you are from Bratislava! I currently live in Vienna from the Philippines and I want to treat you some time for a beer xD

Comment: @MarvieDemit - Thank you very much, it will be nice :) I have my email in my profile, so if really wants to meet with me, it will be super. :)

Comment: I will write you per mail throughout the day :D write you later! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also, it is somewhat similar to jezrael answer.

```
activity_df[activity_df['activities'] == 'sleep']['duration'].iloc[-1]
```

Comment: Except chained indexing is explicitly discouraged in the docs. `loc` is clearer and less error-prone.

Comment: Agreed. It is more effective to use the .loc